# Disable text box without style changing?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can you disable an HTML text box without having the browser change the visual appearance of the textbox?

We disable with JQuery: `$(".datepick").attr('readonly', 'readonly');`

Works fine but in Firefox the text box appears with a grey background and a thick border.  We want to prevent this from happening.

Reason we are doing this is to make a JQuery date picker text box read only (so the user has to use the calendar popup area).

Comment: When I use readonly in Firefox (3.6.12), it does not give me a gray background nor a different border.

Comment: I'm not getting the different styles either. I can't solve the DatePicker part, but here's some CSS to override the "disabled" style:input[disabled]
{
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-color: #404040;
    border-width: 2px 1px 1px 2px;
} (based on the default Firefox styles)

Comment: You should be able to use [`ime-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/ime-mode) here in combination with read-only but I can't get it to work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do it by blurring the text input on `focus`:

```
$('.datepick').focus(function(){
    this.blur();
});
```

Alternatively, you could just disable text entry in the input:

```
$('.datepick').keydown(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I tried the `e.preventDefault();`..   it worked except I noticed on Chrome the delete key still worked.   I couldn't enter text but I could delete it after selecting a date using the control - not what I'd like..

Comment: @Marcus I've edited my question to suggest using `keydown` rather than `keypress`.  I prefer the first technique, however.

Comment: The first solution (blur) doesn't work for me in Chrome.  The second solution looks good!

Comment: this does not seem to work on Safari mobile. Any solution for that?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to override the styling for a disabled input box, explicitly set the styling for an input text box like so:

```
input[type=text] {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
}
/* alternatively you could add textarea to this as well */
```

additionally you could set a css class like 'disabled' whenever you set the input to disabled and use a disabled css style like so:

```
input[type=text].disabled {
  /* disabled styling goes here */
}
```

and then have some code like this:

```
$(some_input).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$(some_input).addClass('disabled');
```

and to reenable the field you could try something like:

```
$(some_input).removeAttr('disabled');
$(some_input).removeClass('disabled');
```

Comment: Just to simplify DJ's answer, you can set a global styling for all disabled text types like so: input[type='text']:disabled { /*styling*/ }, and then just toggle the disabled attribute as needed. We use this method which works perfectly for those hardcoded and dynamically toggled fields.

Answer (score 0):

The [disabled](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp) attribute of the `input` element prevents focus and input without changed the appearance.

Comment: The disabled attribute also prevents the value in the field from being posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".ui-state-disabled").removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
```

I was working with some draggable/droppable elements and wanted to disable that functionality without changing their appearance.

Answer (score -1):

hows about `attr('disabled', true)`. to re-enable, `removeAttr('disabled')`

http://jsfiddle.net/E9m3K/3/

^ styled disabled, since you asked to **disable**

http://jsfiddle.net/E9m3K/4/

^ styled readonly, so you probably just want to override / explicitly define `border` and `background` in the css.

Comment: That still causes the background to be grey.  AND it stops the JQuery datepicker from working.

Comment: You've been here long enough... read the question before answering.

Comment: @Josh Stodola - a guess is better than nothing. and i don't see anything wrong with my answer. a lot of my selected answers were just guesses.. if im going to get downvoted for guessing i dont see the point of using SO.